# UITextField? is not convertible to 'UITextField' after XCode 7 update

Tags: swift, xcode6, swift2, ios9, xcode7

After I updated to `XCode 7`, I am now receiving this error "`UITextField`? is not convertible to '`UITextField`.' I'm confused on why it can't convert all of a sudden. Any thoughts?

```
     let saveAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Search",
        style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default,
        handler: {(action) in
            let query =
            (alertController.textFields?[0] as UITextField).text ### errors here
            let tag = query
            if !query.isEmpty {
                if self.model.queryForTag(tag) != nil {
                }
                else if isNew {
                    self.model.saveQuery(
                        query, forTag: tag, syncToCloud: true)
                    let indexPath =
                    NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)
                    self.tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath],
                        withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
                    self.forceSearch(indexPath)
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unwrap your optionals correctly. It will fix most of these errors. Both the `textfields` and the `query` will be available after the guard statement

```
let saveAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Search",
    style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default,
    handler: {(action) in

        guard let textFields = alertController.textFields, let first = textFields.first, let query = first.text else {
            return
        }

})
```

p.s. guard statements will also help with your growing pyramid.

Comment: thanks for the input.  this seemed to fix my issue too:(alertController.textFields?[0] as UITextField?)!.text

Comment: please don't ever use code like that. Every time you do a unicorn dies!